# My JSON output is only printing [object] instead of the values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hey guys I'm building a local email app with Python and Javascript that uses the localhost as an API to store data.

When I'm trying to display the JSON email data on the "inbox" page, I'm just getting a bunch of [Object object]s printed out onto the page.  How can I get to the values of these objects again? I'm rusty with Javascript.

I've tried just printing emails.  Emails[0][index].  Emails[index][0].  I'm just getting different variations of the words "object" or "undefined".

How can I print the actual JSON values out on the page?  Thanks

Thanks!

javascript:

```
fetch('/emails/inbox')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(emails => {
      
  
  for (index = 0; index < emails.length; index++) { 
    document.getElementById("emails-view").innerHTML += emails[index];
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try **stringify** and it will show what object you are actually dealing with. It is obvious that the **emails[index]** is an object and not a string.

```
fetch('/emails/inbox')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(emails =>
{
    for (index = 0; index < emails.length; index++)
    {
        document.getElementById("emails-view").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(emails[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much - however I'm getting a very unreadable format with parenthesis and everything. How do you recommend displaying it in a readable way?  Thanks!

Comment: document.getElementById("emails-view").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(emails[index].body);  I found out this is working better to display each line of code.  Then i'll do it for "recipents" and "subject" too.  Thanks!

Comment: one more thing - how would I get access to the integers in the JSON array?  They don't work when I stringify them.  How can I get the email id code?

Comment: If they don't show up when you stringify it, then it is not part of the object. Are you perhaps referring to the email index?

Answer (score 1):

- You could try formatted stringify like this:

```js
document.getElementById("emails-view").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(emails[index], null, 4);
```

- or better, if you want to know what an email object looks like, then use `console.log` or `debugger` (breakpoints).

`console.log` - you have to open dev tools (console tab), to see logs :)

```js
fetch('/emails/inbox')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(emails =>
{
    for (index = 0; index < emails.length; index++)
    {
        console.log(emails[index]);
    }
}
```

`debugger` -> [breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints):

```js
fetch('/emails/inbox')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(emails =>
{
    debugger;
}
```